# Non-minified Google Analytics code

Tags: blackberry, google-analytics, cordova

I am building a Blackberry application using Phonegap, and would like to use Google Analytics to track some usage in it.  Thanks to dodgy Blackberry browsers, XHR doesn't really work.  There is a replacement in Phonegap that does work fine, but I need to replace the call in the Google Analytics library with the replacement in order for it to work.  That would be easy if I could find a non-minified version of that library, which seems like it would be easy, but hasn't so far.  I'm probably just missing it somewhere, but is there a non-minified version of the GA Javascript code somewhere that I can use and modify?

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js

Comment: Not quite - that doesn't look like the normal async GA script (no XHR call in it, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Google does not officially provide a non-minified version of their async code (nor do they officially offer it for download to host yourself like they did with older versions, though I suppose there's nothin' stopping you from yanking it and doing it anyways).

Comment: Well, I guess you're right, I haven't seen any evidence to the contrary.  That's disappointing.

Comment: Any thoughts why not? Just curious